# Deploy Next.js app on Google Firebase Functions results in 304 and CORS

Tags: firebase, next.js, google-cloud-functions, server-side-rendering

I'm pretty new to Firebase and have 0 experience with it. I was able to deploy a simple SSR Next.js app with Firebase Functions, but everything but the HTML is blocked.
Here are the browser console errors:

```
GET https://us-central1-***.cloudfunctions.net/_next/static/chunks/webpack-9b312e20a4e32339.js net::ERR_ABORTED 403
nextSsrServer:1

GET https://us-central1-***.cloudfunctions.net/_next/static/css/1de8f31efe8bff6d.css 403
nextSsrServer:1

GET https://us-central1-***.cloudfunctions.net/_next/static/chunks/framework-a87821de553db91d.js net::ERR_ABORTED 403
nextSsrServer:1

GET https://us-central1-***.cloudfunctions.net/_next/static/chunks/main-fc7d2f0e2098927e.js net::ERR_ABORTED 403
nextSsrServer:1

GET https://us-central1-***.cloudfunctions.net/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app-43ac001d99fedbd3.js net::ERR_ABORTED 403
nextSsrServer:1

GET https://us-central1-***.cloudfunctions.net/_next/static/8-ZWcbwxHaYCZZFwKFxrO/_buildManifest.js net::ERR_ABORTED 403
nextSsrServer:1

GET https://us-central1-***.cloudfunctions.net/_next/static/8-ZWcbwxHaYCZZFwKFxrO/_ssgManifest.js net::ERR_ABORTED 403
nextSsrServer:1

GET https://us-central1-***.cloudfunctions.net/_next/static/media/cats.e6b8b6a4.webp 403
nextSsrServer:1

GET https://us-central1-***.cloudfunctions.net/_next/static/chunks/pages/index-17605d8ecb730db9.js net::ERR_ABORTED 403
nextSsrServer:1

GET https://us-central1-***.cloudfunctions.net/_next/static/8-ZWcbwxHaYCZZFwKFxrO/_middlewareManifest.js net::ERR_ABORTED 403
favicon-32x32.png:1

GET https://us-central1-***.cloudfunctions.net/images/favicon/favicon-32x32.png 403
favicon-16x16.png:1

GET https://us-central1-***.cloudfunctions.net/images/favicon/favicon-16x16.png 403
nextSsrServer:1 Access to manifest at 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?passive=true&continue=https://uc.appengine.google.com/_ah/conflogin%3Fstate%3D~AJKiYcHcX7iuuOJqs6nHtkizIgVOAItJqT8PjibW2SPtFq-PnvRkaVn9ZN9Q0P3vl-MbHLVNMpkBlkAHrL6WWQPRdD1D6Tl3LRh00gnbFXWn_4BqQceprDIKpQ4l8qEB4ZLFRkFbezzy8PVwa9HlQZc4Rd1qLVaDfkG0FLQl8xkkQW6JS5ForpHJ98dfnKCtRKA8TqaO2HL0nYNCKKhrytjNJIGRnEf_ipAqwVBEgWbU7Ub_T622fEDBKXXlXNf5gEAqSr5DRXKO'(redirected from 'https://us-central1-***.cloudfunctions.net/images/favicon/site.webmanifest') 
from origin 'https://us-central1-***.cloudfunctions.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?passive=true&continue=https://uc.appengine.google.com/_ah/conflogin%3Fstate%3D~AJKiYcHcX7iuuOJqs6nHtkizIgVOAItJqT8PjibW2SPtFq-PnvRkaVn9ZN9Q0P3vl-MbHLVNMpkBlkAHrL6WWQPRdD1D6Tl3LRh00gnbFXWn_4BqQceprDIKpQ4l8qEB4ZLFRkFbezzy8PVwa9HlQZc4Rd1qLVaDfkG0FLQl8xkkQW6JS5ForpHJ98dfnKCtRKA8TqaO2HL0nYNCKKhrytjNJIGRnEf_ipAqwVBEgWbU7Ub_T622fEDBKXXlXNf5gEAqSr5DRXKO:1

GET https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?passive=true&continue=https://uc.appengine.google.com/_ah/conflogin%3Fstate%3D~AJKiYcHcX7iuuOJqs6nHtkizIgVOAItJqT8PjibW2SPtFq-PnvRkaVn9ZN9Q0P3vl-MbHLVNMpkBlkAHrL6WWQPRdD1D6Tl3LRh00gnbFXWn_4BqQceprDIKpQ4l8qEB4ZLFRkFbezzy8PVwa9HlQZc4Rd1qLVaDfkG0FLQl8xkkQW6JS5ForpHJ98dfnKCtRKA8TqaO2HL0nYNCKKhrytjNJIGRnEf_ipAqwVBEgWbU7Ub_T622fEDBKXXlXNf5gEAqSr5DRXKO net::ERR_FAILED 200
```

I tried solutions found here and there regarding CORS, but nothing worked.

This is my server.js file:

```
const { https } = require("firebase-functions");
const { default: next } = require("next");

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const app = next({
  dev,
  conf: { distDir: ".next" },
});

const handle = app.getRequestHandler();
exports.nextSsrServer = https.onRequest((req, res) =>
  app.prepare().then(() => handle(req, res))
);
```

firebase.json:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "out",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "nextSsrServer"
      }
    ]
  },
  "functions": {
    "source": "."
  }
}
```

.firebaserc:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "***"
  }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. :)

Comment: CORS is fairly simple. It only kicks in if the domains are different. What is the domain that you are calling from?  What are the CORS headers that your code is returning to the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved.
Going to the Google docs, I found that I needed to change this:

> firebase deploy --only functions

into this:

> firebase deploy --only functions,hosting"

The first (wrong) command gave a URL I was not supposed to just use, for the functions only.

The second (correct) one actually produced the correct hosting URL I was supposed to use.

No CORS or any issues of any kind anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This question is about cloud function v1. In case anyone run into CORS issue with cloud function v2, you need to set `cors: true` in the firebase function.

checkout my article about firebase hosting with nextjs and cloud functions: https://yihui.dev/firebase-hosting-with-nextjs-and-cloud-functions

github example: https://github.com/yihui-he/firebase-nextjs-example